# populating list item through json object reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs, frontend

i have a json file that i fetch from a url then i put this object into a state variable, then when the user enters a city name in the search bar i fetch what the user entered and comapre it to my object's row location_city and then populate the card item accordingly, but the showResult function is not working for some reason and i can not figure it out, and when i press the button it keeps logging to the console the object fetched

update: it started magically working without me actually doing anything, there might have been a lagging problem or something, but anyway i still have the thread up because i would love if someone could tell me how i can implement the search function better and actually be able to populate more than one list item, and also if someone could help me make the slider navigation better , like when you click next on the last picture it goes to the first one and vice versa

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card.js';

export default class Slider extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
   super()
    this.state = {
      imgArray: [ "/img/work1.jpg", "/img/work2.jpg", "/img/work3.jpg"],
      imgNo: 0,
      price: null,
      location: null,
  image: null,
  name: null,
  score: null,
  url: "https://www.deskbookers.com/nl-nl/sajax.json?q=Amsterdam&type=-&people=any&favorite=0&pid=&sw=52.293753%2C4.634942&ne=52.455562%2C5.162286&ids=17201%2C19640%2C13692%2C13691%2C12136%2C17938%2C15292%2C14886%2C14885%2C14884%2C14883%2C15730%2C15353%2C15351%2C15330%2C15080%2C17290%2C15454%2C15451%2C15379",
    current: "/img/work1.jpg",
  search: null,
  resultObject: null,
  headlines: ["Pink Floyd Office", "Led Zeppelin Mania", "Central Perk Friends"],
  headline : "Pink Floyd Office"
};
 }

  componentDidMount(){
  this.serverRequest = $.get(this.state.url, function(result){
var info =  result;
console.log(info);
this.setState({
  resultObject:info
})
  }.bind(this));
 }

  nextImg(){
if(this.state.imgNo < 2 && this.state.imgNo >=0 ){
    this.setState({
    imgNo : ++this.state.imgNo ,
    current: this.state.imgArray[this.state.imgNo],
  headline: this.state.headlines[this.state.imgNo]
  })
    console.log(this.state.imgNo);
  }
 }

  prevImg(){
if(this.state.imgNo >= 1  && this.state.imgNo < 3 ){
    this.setState({
    imgNo : --this.state.imgNo,
    current: this.state.imgArray[this.state.imgNo],
  headline: this.state.headlines[this.state.imgNo]
  })
    console.log(this.state.imgNo);
  }
  }

  searchQuery(){
this.setState({
  search: this.refs.searchValue.value
})

  }

  showResult(){
var i;
for(i = 0; i<this.state.resultObject.rows.length; i++){
    if(this.state.search == this.state.resultObject.rows[i].location_city){
      this.setState({
        price: this.state.resultObject.rows[i].day_price,
        location: this.state.resultObject.rows[i].location_city,
        image: this.state.resultObject.rows[i].image_urls2[0],
        name: this.state.resultObject.rows[i].location_name,
        score: this.state.resultObject.rows[i].location_rating
      })
    }
}

  }

 render(){

return(
  <div>
    <div class="slider ">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src={this.state.current} class="main-img" />
            <div class="headline"><span>{this.state.headline}</span></div>
        </div>
        <img src="/img/slider-left.png" class="slider-arrow" onClick={this.prevImg.bind(this)} />
        <img src="/img/slider-right.png" class="slider-arrow slider-right" onClick={this.nextImg.bind(this)} />
      <div class="search-container">
        <input onChange={this.searchQuery.bind(this)} type="text" ref="searchValue" name="search"  placeholder="City name..." class="search-bar" />
        <button onClick={this.showResult.bind(this)} class="search-button">Sit me!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="card-list">
      <Card price={this.state.price} location={this.state.location} image={this.state.image}
            score={this.state.score} name={this.state.name}>
      </Card>
    </ul>
  </div>    
  );
```

}
    }

Comment: Why are you binding this to the showResults function?

Comment: @NicolaPedretti i am new to react js but from what i understand i thought you have to bind this to all functions you use ?

Comment: Have you tried adding any `console.log`'s to check if you've got a match and that `state.search` is populated? Also, I'm assuming you are entering in an exact match to a `location_city ` value as well as that is the only thing that will work

Comment: @user3209048 you don't _have_ to bind all your functions to `this`, only if you want/need that method's `this` to refer to the class instance. Because your methods are calling `this.setState`, they will need to be explicitly bound in the way you did.

Comment: @RobM. ok now i understand the use of bind this so in this case i assume i am using it correctly, secondly, yes i have added even console.log("sometext"); to the beginning of the function showResult before anything else happens, but it doesnt even excute that

Comment: The only problem I see is that you are using `class` instead of `className` in your HTML attributes, fix that and see if your problem is resolved.

Comment: @RobM. no thats not the problem, i use a plugin that allows me to use class instead of className